# JSON key-globbing

Tags: json, key, glob, jq

On the `jq` manual page there are a few examples of output formatting, particularly some shortcuts for when you want to just echo exactly what was in the input JSON.

What if I want to echo exactly what was in the input, but only for keys that match a certain pattern?

For example, given input like so ...

```
[
{"Name":"Widgets","Size":10,"SymUS":"Widg","SymCN":"Zyin","SymJP":"Kono"},
{"Name":"Blodgets","Size":400,"SymUS":"Blodg","SymAU":"Blod","SymJP":"Kado"},
{"Name":"Fonzes","Size":11,"SymRU":"Fyet","SymBR":"Foao"}
]
```

Say I want to select all objects where the `Name` ends in "ets" and then display the `Name` and all attributes of the form `Sym*`.  All I know about those attributes is that there will be one or more per JSON object, and the names have the format `Sym` followed by a two-letter ISO country code.

I would like to just do this:

```
jq '.[] | select(.Name | endswith("ets")) | {Name, Sym*}'
```

but that's not a thing.

Is this just not something `jq` is designed to handle in a single operation?  Should I do a first pass through the file to collect all the possible keys and then list them all explicitly via a `slurpfile`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key to a simple solution to the problem is `to_entries`, as described in the online manual.  With your example data, the following filter produces the output shown below, in accordance with what I understand to be the expectations:

```
.[]
| select(.Name | test("ets$"))
| {Name} + (to_entries | map(select(.key|test("^Sym"))) | from_entries)
```

You might want to refine the regex tests, and/or make other minor adjustments.

Output:

```
{
  "Name": "Widgets",
  "SymUS": "Widg",
  "SymCN": "Zyin",
  "SymJP": "Kono"
}
{
  "Name": "Blodgets",
  "SymUS": "Blodg",
  "SymAU": "Blod",
  "SymJP": "Kado"
}
```

Comment: Ok, I haven't learned the `to_entries`, `from_entries` parts of the language yet.  I will learn those and take another look at this answer.  Also the `+` operator in the object formation at the end is new to me.  That's very helpful.

Comment: Okay, that's exactly what I needed.  I also learned to abbreviate your approach using `with_entries(select(.key|test("^Sym")))`.